# How to hide email in cloud functions mailer? Or how to get an official gmal account? - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

Recently Ive set a nodemailer with cloud functions to mail users about some specific actions in firebase.

In the mail options:

```
const mailOptions = {
  from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
}
```

Unfortunately, it shows the address from which Ive sent the email. And this is actually my private google account I don't really want to let user be able to see it when he receives the email. It shows `MyApp <myapp@gmail.com>`.

**Q1**: Is there a way to hide it?

**However**, I would accept it if I would have some official gmail account, with professional name, like: `offerSender@myApp.com`.

**Q2**: Does Google provides some customizable email box for firebase users, so I can mail users from that specific box and use some nice custom name? (I dont want to use my private one)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending mail through gmail, you can't change the reply address from the one that's used to authenticate with the gmail server.  If you want your mail to appear from some other account, use a mail service that gives you this option.  You will likely have to pay some money for it.